# Updating GUI from thread C#, without binding to UI controls

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, user-interface, .net-3.5

It is know that Invoke method is used when u need to update gui from other thread. But How can I implement this without binding control to code?

Here's my test class:

```
class test
{
   public List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
    public int nThreads = 0;
    public int maxThreads = 5;

    public void DoWork(object data)
    {
        string message = (string)data;
        //MessageBox.Show(message);        


    }

    public void CreateThread(object data)
    {
        if (nThreads >= maxThreads)
            return;
        Thread newThread = new Thread(DoWork);
        threads.Add(newThread);
        newThread.IsBackground = true;
        newThread.Start(data);
        nThreads++;


    }

    public void WindUpThreads()
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("count: " + nThreads.ToString());
        for(int i = 0; i < threads.Count; i++)
        {
            if (threads[i].IsAlive == false)
            {
                threads[i].Abort();
                threads.RemoveAt(i);
               //MessageBox.Show("removing at " + i.ToString());
            }

        }

        nThreads = threads.Count;
    }

}
```

The question is = what tecnique I must use in order to update gui but not hardcode control into class? I've tried to pass delegate to DoWork Method, but this doesn't work (http://pastebin.com/VaSYFxPw). Thanks!

I'm using WinForms, .NET 3.5

Here's the button_click handler:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        test thTest = new test();
        string[] strings;
        try
        {

            strings = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\users\\alex\\desktop\\test.txt");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return;
        }

        bool flag = true;
        int counter = 0;
        int dataCount = strings.Length;

        while (flag == true)
        {
            if (counter >= dataCount)
            {
                flag = false;
            }

            while (thTest.nThreads < thTest.maxThreads)
            {
                if (flag == false)
                    break;

                thTest.CreateThread(strings[counter]);
                //Data d = new Data();
                //d.deleg = AddItem;
                //d.mess = strings[counter];
                //thTest.CreateThread((object)d);
                //MessageBox.Show(counter.ToString());
                counter++;
            }

            thTest.WindUpThreads();

            if (flag == false)
            {
                do
                {
                    thTest.WindUpThreads();

                } while (thTest.nThreads != 0);
            }



        }

        listBox1.Items.Add("Done");

    }
```

The idea is that I'am launching threads for each task I want to process. After while I'am checking are there completed tasks, then they being shutdowned and new ones are launched until there no more tasks left.

Comment: Every List<> has a .Count property, you can use it instead of nThreads. In the for loop you remove items from the list. That can be problematic. Imagine a list with 2 items. The loop starts with i=0 and then it removes the 0th item. Now the list has only 1 item and when it tries to access list[1] it will fail.

Comment: What kind of framework do you use? WinForms? WPF? ...?

Comment: @DennisKuypers, but I'am already using .Count. Or you what do You mean?

Comment: Which controls are in the UI ? . In your code example I can not recognize any UI controls you are trying to use. What do you exactly mean with binding ? Is your project WinForms or WPF ?

Comment: You can remove the `nThreads` completely. Where you need it, you just put  `threads.Count`

Comment: @MaximFleitling, I've updated post. I mean that I don't want to hardcode controls into DoWork method, so logic and UI can be divided.

Comment: If you want to separate your logic from UI you will need kind of UIManager. This one will know when to update the UI when your logic inform it about changes and it knows about UI components which have to be updated. I also recommend Queue<string> to keep you outstanding work. I understood that you want have only 5 Threads running at ones. so you can feed your thread pool from the queue.

Comment: @MaximFleitling, I need to do it using Threads class without anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than making `DoWork` responsible for updating the UI with the results of the operation it performs, simply have it return the value:

```
//TODO change the type of the result as appropriate
public string DoWork(string message)
{
    string output = "output";
    //TODO do some work to come up with the result;
    return output;
}
```

Then use `Task.Run` to create a `Task` that represents that work being done in a thread pool thread.  You can then await that task from your button click handler.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    test thTest = new test();
    //I'd note that you really should pull out reading in this file from your UI code; 
    //it should be in a separate method, and it should also be reading 
    //the file asynchronously.
    string[] strings;
    try
    {
        strings = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\\users\\alex\\desktop\\test.txt");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return;
    }
    foreach (var line in strings)
    {
        var result = await thTest.DoWork(line);
        listBox1.Items.Add(result);
    }
    listBox1.Items.Add("Done");
}
```

If you really want to be old school about it, you can use a `BackgroundWorker` instead.  Simply do your work in the `DoWork` handler, setting the result (through the argument) when you've computed it, and update the UI with the result in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler.  This lets you keep the UI and non-UI work separate, although it's far less powerful, general purpose, and extensible, as the newer features.

Comment: Its Dot.Net 3.5 there is as I know no async/await functionality

Comment: @Servy, Thanks for nice example, but I need to do it using only Threading stuff.

Comment: @MaximFleitling It's a feature of C#, not the framework.  So yes, you can in fact use `async/await` with .NET 3.5.

Comment: @АлександрПушкин You could re-create all of these tools from scratch, using those tools, but why bother doing that when you could just use the ones MS has created for you?

Answer (score 0):

> The question is = what tecnique I must use in order to update gui but not hardcode control into class? I've tried to pass delegate to DoWork Method, but this doesn't work

This is indeed the one of the possible techniques. It doesn't work because you have a blocking loop in the UI thread - the most of the code inside the `button1_Click` handler. It doesn't matter that you spawn additional worker threads - that code keeps the UI thread busy, thus `Control.Invoke` / `Control.BeginInvoke` doesn't work because they are processed by the UI thread message loop, which in this case has no chance to do that. The end result is a classical deadlock.

So, you can use the delegate approach, but to make it work, you need to move that code in a separate thread. Something like this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    var worker = new Thread(DoWork);
    worker.IsBackground = true;
    worker.Start();
}

private void OnWorkComplete(Exception error)
{
    if (error != null)
        MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
    button1.Enabled = true;
}

private void DoWork()
{
    Exception error = null;
    try { DoWorkCore(); }
    catch (Exception ex) { error = ex; }
    Invoke(new Action(OnWorkComplete), error);
}

private void DoWorkCore()
{
    test thTest = new test();
    // NOTE: No try/catch for showing message boxes, this is running on a non UI thread
    string[] strings = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\users\\alex\\desktop\\test.txt");

    bool flag = true;
    int counter = 0;
    int dataCount = strings.Length;
    // The rest of the code...
    // Pass a delegate to the other threads.
    // Make sure using Invoke when you need to access/update UI elements
}
```